# Arguments for methods in xml

Tags: android, xml, arguments

Instead of having two methods, I want to use one method and pass in different arguments.
Currently my button in XML has

```
<Button android:onClick="switchToQuickView"/>
```

but I want to do something like

```
<Button android:onClick="switchTo("Quickie")/>
```

instead.

Comment: You can't do that with reasonable effort.